# How to make height of overlay depend on height of textview?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make the height of an overlay depend on the weight of a textview. As below, I have an image in the background and a semi-transparent overlay that acts as the background for some text.

[image]

I'm using a FrameLayout that wraps up the background image, the overlay and the text as follows:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
/>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <View
            android:id="@+id/overlay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/overlay_box_white"/>
</FrameLayout>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/userFeedHuntCardFrontSummary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Does anyone know how to make the height of the overlay box to have a top and bottom margins of say 4dp from the textview?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, I think it will do what you are asking for?

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />
   <LinearLayout 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="bottom"
             android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
              android:background="@color/overlay_box_white">
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userFeedHuntCardFrontSummary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
 </FrameLayout>
```